# Is there a C# class to verify if a file is Catalog signed and trusted

Tags: c#, powershell, certificate, x509certificate, sign

I need to verify all of the files at rest on my local hard drive match their digital signature if they are signed. I have the C# code to do this for Authenticode signed files but I do not have the C# code to check if a file is Catalog signed like C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe. I have seen many examples using PowerShell runspace Get-AuthenticodeSignature but this method creates a dependency on PowerShell 5.x to be installed and some of my systems are still at an older version. All of the answers I have found either do not check the Catalog before checking for an Authenticode signature or they leverage PowerShell runspace. Another twist on this is c:\windows\explorer.exe, It is both Catalog signed and Authenticode signed but the Catalog signature is the correct signature to use for validating if it has been tampered with.

Comment: `Install-Module -Name Authenticode`? The package is written for oder PowerShell version ( `#Requires -version 2.0` ).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `SignTool verify /v /pa CatalogFileName.cat` from the Windows SDK. The executable file must be depolyed with some *.dlls to run. There are other tools (like SysInternals) which do the job also.

If you want to go a more native way you might find the following C# code useful:

- https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a11810bf3328a400347b17c14eec968e7ebda241/src/System.Management.Automation/security/Authenticode.cs#L295
- https://github.com/andyvand/ProcessHacker/blob/75bb2e692a09e7cffa6723ce629c37fc0da302ff/1.x/branches/ph-plugins/ProcessHacker.Native/Cryptography.cs

Comment: I like your cryptography.cs link the best out of everything I have found. It has some flaws but it works. A catalog entry should always be checked first before an Authenticode signature. In the Authenticode check the coder does not correctly identify the CN= signer if CN= is not the first item.

Comment: You are welcome. As it is open source you could be so kind to let the author know or even provide an pull request with a fixed version.